# Show Fiscal Year Dynamically - SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created an Oracle SQL query that produces current year data:

```
SELECT A.ITEMNO, A.DESCRIP, SUM(RD.QTYRETURNED) AS "TOTAL QTY RETURNED"
FROM   RMA R LEFT OUTER JOIN RMA_DETAIL RD ON R.ID=RD.RMA_ID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ARINVT A ON RD.ARINVT_ID=A.ID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ARCUSTO C ON C.ID = A.ARCUSTO_ID
WHERE  ((R."CLOSED" IS  NULL ) OR ((R.CLOSED='N' OR R.CLOSED='Y'))) AND
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM R.RMA_DATE) = EXTRACT(YEAR FROM SYSDATE)
GROUP BY A.ITEMNO, A.DESCRIP
ORDER BY "TOTAL QTY RETURNED" DESC
```

I am needed to create a query that returns our fiscal year (12/1 - 11/30) so I created this:

```
SELECT A.ITEMNO, A.DESCRIP, SUM(RD.QTYRETURNED) AS "TOTAL QTY RETURNED"
FROM   RMA R LEFT OUTER JOIN RMA_DETAIL RD ON R.ID=RD.RMA_ID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ARINVT A ON RD.ARINVT_ID=A.ID
             LEFT OUTER JOIN ARCUSTO C ON C.ID = A.ARCUSTO_ID
WHERE  ((R."CLOSED" IS  NULL ) OR ((R.CLOSED='N' OR R.CLOSED='Y'))) AND
     R.RMA_DATE >= ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'), -7) AND R.RMA_DATE < 
     ADD_MONTHS(TRUNC(SYSDATE, 'MONTH'),   5)
GROUP BY A.ITEMNO, A.DESCRIP
ORDER BY "TOTAL QTY RETURNED" DESC
```

These are queries that are used to create BI Dashboards. The issue with the fiscal year query is that when the sysdate month changes, then so will the data. What is the cleanest way to go about doing this? I'm just beginning with SQL, so any links to learning articles or explanations will go a long way. TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can try a query like the one below. It calculates the "begin" and "end" dates based on what month you are currently in

```sql
  SELECT A.ITEMNO, A.DESCRIP, SUM (RD.QTYRETURNED) AS "TOTAL QTY RETURNED"
    FROM RMA R
         LEFT OUTER JOIN RMA_DETAIL RD ON R.ID = RD.RMA_ID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ARINVT A ON RD.ARINVT_ID = A.ID
         LEFT OUTER JOIN ARCUSTO C ON C.ID = A.ARCUSTO_ID
   WHERE     ((R."CLOSED" IS NULL) OR ((R.CLOSED = 'N' OR R.CLOSED = 'Y')))
         AND R.RMA_DATE >=
             TO_DATE (
                    CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
                        WHEN 12 THEN TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
                        ELSE TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12), 'YYYY')
                    END
                 || '-12-01',
                 'YYYY-MM-DD')
         AND R.RMA_DATE <
             TO_DATE (
                    CASE EXTRACT (MONTH FROM SYSDATE)
                        WHEN 12 THEN TO_CHAR (ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, 12), 'YYYY')
                        ELSE TO_CHAR (SYSDATE, 'YYYY')
                    END
                 || '-12-01',
                 'YYYY-MM-DD')
GROUP BY A.ITEMNO, A.DESCRIP
ORDER BY "TOTAL QTY RETURNED" DESC
```